# Message source cant find key

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a project that has the following message source configured:

```
 @Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        final ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        source.setBasename("i18n/core/messages");
        source.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        source.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        return source;
    }
```

I want to use this "core" project as a lib for my app project. The messages are defined in this core, as resources.

In this same core project i have a **@ControlerAdvice** that gets all the exception that my application throws, as following:

```
@ExceptionHandler
    public void unknownException(final Exception ex)  {

        if (ex instanceof StudioException){
            throw (StudioException) ex;
        }

        final UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        final String[] strings = {uuid.toString()};
        String message = messageSource.getMessage("exception.not.identified",strings, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
        final UnknownError unknownError = new UnknownError();
        unknownError.setUuid(uuid.toString());
        unknownError.setLogger(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));
        unknownErrorService.save(unknownError);
        throw new StudioException(message);
```

The problem is that when i use my core project as dependency of my app project, and an exception is thronw, the **ExceptionHandler** is called but the **messageSource** cant find the key.

I tried to set the basename with "classpath:...", i changed the directory strtucure of the resources in the core to be diferent from the app project but no success.

This is where are my i18n properties:
[image: Properties files]

Does anyone knows how can i solve this, having the keys and the message logic inside my core project?

Comment: it seems the file is not found.Do you have that file in corresponding dir (i18n/core/messages.properies) .File name can be messages.properies or messages_en.properies or messages_en_US.properies (locale being US)

Comment: Yes i do. I'll update my the question with the printscreen

Comment: try with setBasename("classpath:i18n/core/messages")

Comment: i tried already, without success.

Comment: i m sure you have tried using "classpath:/i18n/core/messages" as well. :)

Comment: Can you write a main class to load it. InputStream  input = new FileInputStream("i18n/core/message_en_US.properties"); and  other options you tried with. It seems something wrong getting that from classpath

Comment: It is a springboot application, so i cant haive it in the main =/

Comment: i just tried and it works perfect. source.setBasename("classpath:/i18n/core/message")

Comment: And i see there is a messages.properties as well in your classpath. which means if this is found then id doesnt even try to go for messages_en_US.properties. Thus you may delete messages.properties and give it a try .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138648/discussion-between-surya-and-jeyvison).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by [surya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3003337/surya) :

> try with setBasename("classpath:i18n/core/messages")

solved the problem .